# Accessing existing session data from a subdomain in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-cookies

I have two websites on the same server -

1) `subdomain.example.com` where users log in. I setup a session cookie with domain as `.example.com`

2) my second website is at `example.com` which is a brand new CI powered website and no functionality has been added yet. I added a plain php file at `example.com/plain.php` to test if I am able to access data across all domain variations.

In `subdomain.example.com/login.php` I setup session cookie as

```
session_name('mysess');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

In `http://example.com/Plain.php`

```
session_name('mysess');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION);
```

In My CodeIgniter website `http://subdomain.example.com/application/config.php`

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'mysess';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '.example.com'; 
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```

Once users login at `subdomain.example.com` I can see the session data at `example.com/plain.php` without any issues but as soon as I view any page on `example.com/mycontroller/mymethod` it overwrites the session data and I lose all the session data set after login at `subdomain.example.com`

I need that same session data on both of the sites to see if a user is logged in or not.

What changes do I need to make in CI config to be able to get that data?

Comment: The only thing that I can see is different between your session configs is that the subdomain cookie lifetime is different than CodeIgniter's "sess_expiration". What happens if you set "sess_expiration" to 0?

Comment: I tried zero for sess_expiration but it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: Although I don't see why it would make a difference, some people here on SO seemed to have success setting the cookie prefix. Have you seen those questions/answers? Weird problem you're having. I subscribed to your CodeIgniter forum thread because I'm very interested.

Comment: I tried a cookie prefix but still no luck.